# Сохранение объекта в файл

Tags: java, android

Есть объект который нужно записать в файл.

состоит объект из  таких полей:

```
private Organization organization;
private int status = -1;
private Drawable photo;
private ByteArrayInputStream avatar;
```

при попытке сериализации получаю ошибку:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BitmapDrawable
```

Подскажите каким образом можно сохранить такой объект в файл? Или во что можно конвертировать изображения (преимущественно интересует Drawable), что бы их  можно было сохранить.

Answer (score 3):

1. `Drawable` хранить в ресурсах.
2. `ByteArrayInputStream` нельзя сериализовать это абсолютно абстрактный класс, как все его методы, кроме его конфигов состояния. Просто задумайтесь что вы хотите получить после десериализации Object данного класса? Вот именно - ничего, это буфер для `InputStream`. Как варинат решения, пометьте его transient, при десериализации, будет иметь `null`.

Comment: а каким образом можно сохранить битмап в ресурсы?

Comment: да Drawable конечно, BitMap это лишь его простейший вид, ну суть одна

Comment: Да мне Drawable то и нужен, как его в момент выполнения можно сохранить в папку ресурсов, я так понял, что так сделать не получится

Comment: А в этом вопрос, ну работайте с BitMap->File ) сохраняйте в папку ресурсов. Я думаю есть много реализаций, просто что в голову пришло.

Comment: я понял что нужно ее сохранять в папку ресурсов вопрос в том как это сделать

Comment: @KirillStoianov, автор имеет в виду, видимо, что вам надо или в `res/drawable` хранить изображения, в объекте оперируя только с их `id` в `R` классе или, если они у вас из сети качаются и вообще не статические, то их вам надо в некую вами созданную папку на устройстве сохранять в вами же созданных файлах. А при сериализации хранить не `Drawable` а ссылку на файл.

Comment: Можно поподробней, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Убедись, что все поля сериализуемого объекта также сериализуемы. Если хоть одно поле не Serializable, то ничего не получится

Comment: Два последних  поля в объекте не сериализуемы, я думал это очевидно исходя из  исключений которые я получил, вопрос в том, как это исправить?

Comment: Drawable можно заменить строкой с именем картинки и, уже после десериализации, получать картинку из ресурсов. Как заменить ByteArrayInputStream, я не в курсе, придется помозговать. К слову, ВСЕ объекты реального мира можно описать примитивами и массивами (списками) из этих примитивов. Если ты пытаешься сериализовать что-то другое, значит ты 100% делаешь что-то неверно

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете не сериализовать Drawable в файл, а вместо этого сохранять его в res/drawable,  а его имя записывать  в сериализуемый объект? правильно? Мне такой вариант не подходит так как мне нужно сохранять картинки динамически

Comment: С каждым новым сообщением я узнаю о вашей задаче все больше и больше, я пасую

Comment: Задача одна, она же описана в вопросе, нужно сохранить объект который содержит Drawable либо отдельно как то сохранить Drawable